# Insert span tag before # content text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to know how to insert span tag before the # sign content using jquery. Sorry for this question. I'm still new to jquery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var text = $(".name a").text();
        //alert(text);
        if (text.contains("#")) {
            alert("yes");
        }
        else {
            alert("no");
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="name">
<a href="">This is a link contens #104004</a>
</div>
```

Output should be like this

```
<div class="name">
<a href="">This is a link contens <span>#104004</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var 
      textElement = $(".name > a"),
      text = textElement.text();

  textElement.html(text.replace(/#[0-9]+/g, '<span>$&</span>'));
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
<a href="">This is a link contens #104004</a>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Update:

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: `replace()` allows you to replace the matched text with some other string. When a
>   match is found, if you want to include the matched text in the
>   replacement string, you can access it using $&.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> var s = 'HelloJavaScriptWorld';
>
> s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "_$&"); // "_Hello_Java_Script_World"
> ```

Comment: why $& is needed ? I see doesn't work if replace that sign!! If u appreciate explain in your post.

Comment: When a match is found, if you want to include the matched text in the replacement string, you can access it using $&. Here's how to add an underscore before the match while keeping the match. var s = new String('HelloJavaScriptWorld'); s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "_$&");

Answer (score 2):

```
 var text=$(".name a").text();
 text.replace(/(\#[\w]*)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
```

Im not sure if it will work please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Shrikanth Buds' answer:

First add a class to all such links that you want to process. I have used class 'hashcontainers' for this example. Then, try below code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".hashcontainers").each(function(index){
            var text = $(".name a").text();
            if (text.contains("#")) {
                //alert("yes");
                var updatedHTMLString = text.replace(/(\#[\w]*)/g,"<span>$1</span>");
                $(this).html( updatedHTMLString );
            }           
        });//each
    });
</script>

<div class="name">
<a href="" class="hashcontainers">This is a link contens #104004</a>
</div>
```